# Is there any process to prevent the abusing of close on-hold?

Tags: support

Five closing requests are placed on my question about Eclipse passing variable to external tool (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341583/is-there-a-variable-for-class-name-when-calling-external-tools-in-eclipse), because obviously they cannot understand it.

I got so upset that I examined answer history of every these five users, except one user, other of them had never answered one single Eclipse question. So that I believe it is a case of abusing. It hurts my feeling about the quality of this community.

- I'm not asking why it is on-hold or how to re-open it!

Comment: There is the review queue... I've closed quite a few questions where I have little domain knowledge, and rightly so.

Comment: But all 5 of those uses have 3000+ rep, which shows that they have been on the site for a while and know the site. Because of this, we trust their judgement for what a good question is.

Comment: Really? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A913543+%5Beclipse%5D http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A188331+%5Beclipse%5D http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2422776+%5Beclipse%5D

Comment: Why do you feel this is an example of **abuse**? Do you feel that five unconnected users decided to target your question for no reason? Or that one person is using multiple accounts to close it? If so, what would be the motivation?

Comment: You question essentially boils down to looking in the Eclipse documentation.  Can you respond to my comment on your SO question?

Comment: Yep, that happens.  I've had people vote to close my questions before because they didn't use the software and didn't understand the need.  I've cast the first reopen vote for you, good luck.

Comment: @TheGrinch, documentation is not always easy to find answers in, there are hundreds of thousands of answers on SO that could be answered from the documentation, but it's not always that easy.

Comment: Guys, I'm not asking how to re-open it.

Comment: @waiwai93 thanks for the tip. Just learned to search by this way, I was browsed page by page and obviously missed it.

Comment: @The Grinch please read it before judging me.

Comment: (1) Firstly, you need 3k reputation to close questions. That hopefully usually requires understanding (most of) the site guidelines to get. (2) Randomly voting to close questions is not going to do all that much - 4 other users need to agree first. (3) In really, really bad cases, the user can probably manually be banned (from the site) (but given #2, "really, really bad cases" probably don't exist or, at the very least, difficult to find). (4) If these users are voting to close from the review queue, there are audits to check that users are doing what they are supposed to.

Answer (score 10):

If a question of yours is closed, or there are votes to close it, and you don't agree with them, you can simply post a comment that either explains why you feel the close reason doesn't apply, or asking others to explain why, specifically, they feel the question should be closed.  (In this specific case, your question is closed as unclear; you could, for example, post a comment asking what aspects of your question readers find confusing.)  If the discussion over it's closure ends up becoming fairly extensive, beyond just a few comments, consider posting on meta with a link to the question asking for the community to discuss whether or not the question should be closed, so as to avoid polluting the question with too much meta-discussion.

On a side note, in most cases a person doesn't need to be particularly knowledable about a particular domain to know whether or not it should be closed.  There are some exceptions (in particular, duplicates often require some domain knowledge) but the fact that someone hasn't participated in the given topic much doesn't inherently mean their close votes are inappropriate.

Comment: I'm not asking how to re-open it, thanks anyway.

Comment: @pinxue I wasn't answering how you should reopen it; I was telling you what you should do if you don't understand, or agree with, a decision to close a question.  The response is to post a comment, and if you cannot resolve the issue in comments, to post on meta.  It may very well not result in the question being reopened; but it should result in you understanding why it was closed.

Comment: Well, I have added comments before I post here :-)

Comment: @pinxue You posted comments, but you didn't post the kinds of comments that I said you should.  The first is a bit too broad, although isn't terrible, the last really isn't useful at all; it's not how you go about getting a question reopened, and the second is simply confrontational and looks like you're trying to rant at other users, rather than requesting help understanding what's wrong or how to fix your question.  I'm not surprised others were dis-inclined to respond, assuming they weren't looking to get into an argument.